# Can I provide configurations to a plastic scm sever to automate it's installation?

Tags: automation, plasticscm

So I'm trying to automate my Plastic SCM server. But I can't find any way to install all the configurations without a prompt running `clconfigureserver` in the sever even though I've read the [Admin guide](https://www.plasticscm.com/documentation/administration/plastic-scm-version-control-administrator-guide.shtml) a bunch of times looking for something.

So far I'm thinking that just replacing the XML files in `/opt/plasticscm5/server/*.config` should work. But now I need to figure out how to provide the token to the configuration (or more variables that I may need)

Thanks in advance for the help! I'd like to automate this installation in the best possible way. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly copy the necessary configuration files in the server binaries folder:

*"db.conf"* --> where we configure the database parameters.

*"users.conf"* and "groups.conf" --> where we specify the users and groups.

*"remoting.conf"* --> where we specify the server channels.

*"server.conf"* --> where we configure different server settings and parameters

*"plasticd.lic"* --> the server license

*"plasticd.lic.token"* --> only if you are using a license token.

Comment: Right. I didn't realize about the `plasticd.lic` and `plasticd.lic.token` files. That's what I was looking for. Thanks! Which leads me to another question, Is there a way to encrypt these files? Or that's something that I need to take care of? =)

Comment: No, don´t worry. You don´t have to encrypt the files for the server to read them ;)